# How to remove this kickstand without destroying anything?

Tags: kickstand

I have a 70's Schwinn Collegiate. It has kickstand that's welded to the frame. How can I remove this kickstand from the housing? Looking at the bottom, I can't tell if this pin needs to be pushed in or pulled out.

I want to be able to put it back together afterwards.

[image: kickstand from the bottom]

Comment: Get a cutoff wheel and cut off the kickstand.

Comment: I'm in the middle of a teardown / rebuild. I want to lubricate this and put it back together.

Comment: Well if you can't push it in try pulling it out ;) Altough I would first try to flood it with WD40 or simillar trying to get rid of some internal rust.

Comment: I've added the relevant info from the comments to the title and question body.  I suspect it has to pull out, but that may be very difficult.  My guess is it's pressed into place with no intention that it would ever be removable

Comment: I had one of these, and cut it off with a grinder, then smoothed and painted the bare steel.  The leg and attachments were over a kilogram in weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pin needs to be pulled out.  You can remove it using a wrench inserted in the kickstand for leverage to push the ring and that will loosen up the pin. If you need a visual, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlfXmN7C5TY).  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From memory these are generally unserviceable.

When you lower the leg, the shaft will rotate but will also move over a detent internally.  Try and drop the leg half way so the internal spring is compressed, then look for the largest gap.  Shove a spray straw in there and blast in white-lithium grease (not WD40) and work the leg back and forth.

These are not precision instruments, some force and persuasion may be required.

Don't cut it off, unlike mine, yours looks to be acting as a chainstay bridge, providing reinforcement.  Removing it completely would be bad.

Comment: Definitely serviceable. Even pulling the spring once I got the kickstand off was a piece of cake.

Comment: @tir38 Great work!  If you could add an answer of your own with photos it will really help the next person searching for the same info.  Even just a detailed word summary would help if you didn't take any pictures.